# Android Dropdown List (iPhone style)

Tags: android, list, drop-down-menu, ddl

Could anyone tell me either what this widget is or how it could be recreated? I'm having to port over a iPhone app, and my boss wants me to make it look as similar as possible, but while using android controls. Here is a picture of it in Android:

http://cdn3.staztic.com/screenshots/android-swim-32-2.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a standard thing, but for this purpose, there is a: [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) dialog.

Comment: May I ask you, if you are observing too, that if you tap on some item on QuickAction, it disapears for a short moment before the whole popup is gone? I'd like to know if it's just a problem in my emulator. thank you

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with a PopupWindow (it can also be shown as dropdown) where the background is a custom nine-patch file and the content is a listview (or any other view that fits your needs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that [GreenDroid Library](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid#readme) can do this but I don't know the name of the class to use